# Way to migrate data in bulk which reference record types

Tags: record-type, externalid, data-migration, unique-field, unique

Record Type standard object lacks Unique External Id field and doesn't allow to create a custom Unique External Id field, which brings a challenge to migrate data in bulk which reference record types, since when there are two Record Types even in different object but with the same name, migration script will fail with an error

DUPLICATE_EXTERNAL_ID:Name: more than one record found for external id field: [0121j000003gnr6AAA, 0121j000003gmqXAAQ]:Name -- DUPLICATE_EXTERNAL_ID:Name: more than one record found for external id field: [0121j000003gnr6AAA, 0121j000003gmqXAAQ]:Name -- DUPLICATE_EXTERNAL_ID:Name: more than one record found for external id field: [0121j000003gnr6AAA, 0121j000003gmqXAAQ]:Name -- DUPLICATE_EXTERNAL_ID:Name: more than one record found for external id field: [0121j000003gnr6AAA, 0121j000003gmqXAAQ]:Name --

If one of the record type is unmanaged, you may potentially rename it so that the name becomes unique, but in the case, for example, when there are record types from different managed packages which have the same name and you can't rename any of them, this is a blocker for a data migration.

There is even an [idea on IdeaExchange](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdhArUAJ/use-of-external-id-for-record-type-to-ease-data-migration-efforts) since July 9, 2015, which has only 42 votes, so Salesforce isn't going to take a look to it in the near future.

A workaround suggested by Salesforce Support to use Excel VLOOKUP to get and map the records with RecordTypeId based on the recordtype name, isn't a viable approach if you have thousands or millions of records.

Is there any viable workaround to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think when we need to migrate some data on custom object `X__c` or a standard object, the only reasonable "wheel" we can invent in this case is to perform the following steps.

1. Introduce some custom field `Record Type Developer Name` on the custom object `X__c` in both source and target systems.
2. Copy the value of Record Type developer name to that field on all records. It can be achieved with a trigger or autolaunched flow for new records or as a Batchable script for existing records.
3. Introduce a trigger in the target system to read the value of `Record Type Developer Name` field on the custom object `X__c` and decipher it to the correct value of record type on record insert.
4. Migrate all fields except actual Record Type Id but including field `Record Type Developer Name` to invoke the trigger in the target system.
5. Get happy to overcome this. Maybe get some profit :)